# Looking for the Java equivalent of C#'s XmlConvert.EncodeName

Tags: c#, java, .net, xml

The rules for defining a properly constructed XML name are defined [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-common-syn).

C# has a utility method to convert strings into a valid XML name: [XmlConvert.EncodeName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.encodename%28VS.80%29.aspx).

What is the Java equivalent of this utility method?

**Note**: XML names must begin with a letter, _, or : character. After the first character, be composed only of letters, digits, ., -, _, and : characters.

Answer (score 1):

I've translated the corresponding C# code from MONO to java. You can clone it from Github: https://github.com/ehongyu/XmlConvert.git

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are looking for but how about QName (http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/QName.html), there is a valueOf() method that might be what you are looking for.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not what I am looking for.  QName.valueOf("foo+").toString(); yields "foo+". Note that the "+" was not converted.